# Storing large amounts of updated data, in a session?

Tags: php, session-variables

So I have an application which allows a user to type sentences/paragraphs into a textbox. In the background a timer is running. Every 5 seconds the value of the textbox is to be copied and stored into the database or in an xml file (via ajax). I thought it would be quite unsafe if I updated the db/xml file ever 5 seconds.

My thinking is - when the user presses stop on the timer - it will then save all the data into the database/xml file. Instead of every 5 seconds it gets updated.

However I still need to store the values at each interval. Should I go about using at session with an array inside? How much can a session take. It would look like: `$_SESSION['content'][] = "Massive long string text!";`

Example: User is typing for 10 minutes straight and the body of the text is saved into the session array every 5 seconds. Is this too stressfull? Each paragraph might be 1000 characters in length at each interval.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Don't store large amount of data in the session. Store it on the server side, e.g. using some database.

Comment: Ok. Do you think the server can handle updating every 5 seconds? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch just to be clear, session data is stored server-side, only a cookie id is sent to the browser. However, it's not necessarily a very good storage mechanism, so I see your pojnt.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. It depends upon the server, the amount of simultaneously active web connections, the application, the hardware, etc etc. You should try and measure.

Comment: Ok sure. I will try it but how will I measure it? Sorry I'm not too familiar with PHP code optimization.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a hidden element (e.g. textarea), then a javascript function fill the element every 5 seconds from user_textbox value. To reduce server load, you can store the contents of the hidden element to the database when user_textbox blur.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. But my question regards a user typing into a textarea and through ajax it uploads the text within that textarea (every 5 seconds). Thanks though.